# How to convert object to map?

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I need to convert an object i got from database to a map, how can i do that?

Variable that should contain data inside the object

```
public Map<Byte, Byte> currentSkills = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

How I get that object from the database

```
MongoCollection<Document> users = Database.connection.getDatabase("app").getCollection("users");
Document playerInfo = users.find(eq("Name", username)).first();
player.skills.currentSkills = playerInfo.get("Skills");
```

I made a little research and found some libraries that can do it, is there any way i can do this without using external libraries?

Comment: Side question: why would you need a HashMap if the keys are of type `Byte`? Unless you meant `Byte[]`?

Comment: Of course you can do it without external libraries.  At worst, you could reimplement whatever some suitable library does.  But typically, such a library will have a lot more capabilities than you need for your particular task, so you probably can get away with doing much less.

Comment: In any case, how you might convert an object of one type into an object of a different type depends a lot on the two types involved, and you haven't told us anything about what a `Document` is in your application.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I need it to have a key (skill id) and value (amount)

Comment: @JohnBollinger http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html

Comment: In that case, @user123, I don't get it.  Its documentation clearly says that a `org.bson.Document` is *already* a `java.util.Map` (specifically, a `Map<String, Object>`).  What, then, is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: In fact, you are even *using* that when you invoke the `Document`'s `get()` method.